# can I have a nested lambda expression stored in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, functional-programming

I'd like to parse a string into a lambda expression in C#,
for example, parse `"lt 5"` to `x => x < 5` so I can use it as the argument of `Enumerable.Where`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Enumerable
        .Range(0,10)
        .Select(x => (double)x)
        .Where(Parse("lt 5"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(System.Console.WriteLine);
}

private const List<Tuple<List<string>, Func<double, Func<double, bool>>>> operationList =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<double, Func<double, bool>>>()
    { { "lt <",     val => ( x => x <  val ) }
    , { "le <=",    val => ( x => x <= val ) }
    , { "eq = ==" , val => ( x => x == val ) }
    , { "ne != <>", val => ( x => x != val ) }
    , { "ge >=",    val => ( x => x >= val ) }
    , { "gt >",     val => ( x => x >  val ) } }
    .Select(kv =>
        new Tuple<
            List<string>,
            Func<double, Func<double, bool>>>(
                kv.Key.Split(' ').ToList(),
                kv.Value))
    .ToList();

public static Func<double, bool> Parse(string raw)
{
    var fields = raw.Split(' ');
    var predKey = fields[0].ToLower();

    var predBuilder = operationList.FirstOrDefault(tp =>
        tp.Item1.FirstOrDefault(key => key.Equals(predKey)) != null);

    return predBuilder.Item2(double.Parse(fields[1]));
}
```

First I made a `operationList` that stores a tuple where `Item1` describes all aliases to the operator and `Item2` stores a curried version of the operator.

Then `Parse` will split string `lt 5` into `["lt","5"]` and search the operation according to key `lt`.

Finally, if I can find the operation, `5` will be partial applied to it and the result will be a lambda expression `x => x < val`.

However, the compiler was mad at `{ "lt <",     val => ( x => x <  val ) }` and complained "Expression cannot contain anonymous methods or lambda expressions".

I have no idea about what it means and how to get things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `const` to `readonly` and make it `static`, like so:

```
private readonly static List<Tuple<List<string>, Func<double, Func<double, bool>>>> operationList =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<double, Func<double, bool>>>()
    { { "lt <",     val => ( x => x <  val ) }
    , { "le <=",    val => ( x => x <= val ) }
    , { "eq = ==" , val => ( x => x == val ) }
    , { "ne != <>", val => ( x => x != val ) }
    , { "ge >=",    val => ( x => x >= val ) }
    , { "gt >",     val => ( x => x >  val ) } }
    .Select(kv =>
        new Tuple<
            List<string>,
            Func<double, Func<double, bool>>>(
                kv.Key.Split(' ').ToList(),
                kv.Value))
    .ToList();
```

In C# [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword is used to denote compile time constants, but in your example list is calculated at runtime using LINQ.

In C# `const` values are always static and making it readonly will change field's scope to instance.

Note, that contents of you list might change during execution and `readonly` won't stop you from removing and adding Tuples into a list. Consider using [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) (it's still won't stop you from modifying it, just will make it harder) or using [Immutable Collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx) (which aren't part of **.net BCL**)